# Linting for Ruby < 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rubymine, rubocop

I have a project with many Ruby files, loaded by external program with embedded Ruby interpreter (and some other libraries). I'm trying to use RubyMine and Rubocop to help with development, but the problem is that the said embedded interpreter is of version 1.9.2 and can't be upgraded in any way. Is it possible to still use the Rubocop or other linter inside RubyMine and at the same time to make sure the code is compatible with old interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, [Check this out](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/rubocop.html) and then let RuboCop know the oldest version of Ruby which your project supports with updating .rubocop.yml file:

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 1.9
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that yes, it is possible to change the linter used in RubyMine, there are complete walk-throughs on JetBrains site explaining how. I don't know off the top of my head any linters that specifically work for pre-2.0 versions of Ruby, not to say they don't exist.

The longer answer is that it really won't make much difference if the interpreter is running through another program, and not using a real Ruby installation, and any linter is not going to reliably work for you. There will be plenty of code that a linter will still think is perfectly acceptable, but fail when running in an embedded VM.

```
# Linter thinks this perfectly fine, part of 1.9.2 standard library
require 'base64' 

# Still thinks this perfectly fine. This all fails miserably though
Base64.encode64('My string')
```

The most obvious examples would be the entire standard library, gems, rake, and anything that is not part of the "core" library. Basic rule of thumb, if you have to `require` a script (excluding your project's local scripts), it is not going to work.

Another reason it could never be reliable is that you do not know if the embedded Ruby interpreter has been altered, or removed features from Ruby for their purposes, and a linter would have even less way of knowing that. Years ago I dabbled with the RPG Maker series, and discovered the hard way that their were certain built in features of Ruby that were removed (or at least hidden) from their custom build.

If you are familiar with Ruby, then you can obviously steer clear of the major and most common 2.0+ changes that Ruby implemented to the core library, but the only reliable way to know (even with a linter), is testing, which you will need to do anyway ( or at least you should). RubyMine has good support for automating this with Minitest and RSpec.

Comment: I'm just looking for some help, nothing more. Of course, the concrete interpreter features (btw, you guessed right, it's all about RPG Maker :)) must be taken care of by myself.

Comment: I assumed by specifically being `1.9.2` it was RM :-). Totally understand, just keep in mind some of the "false positives" you will get I mentioned. If you used to coding in RM, and not with pure Ruby, you will be unlikely to be needing anything outside of the core-lib anyways, so no biggie. Since most of stdlib is Ruby scripts, you could even copy-paste anything you need to your project in many cases.